# How can I find the first element returned from a <> type of list returned by SQLite?

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin

I have this code I am reviewing:

```
           var phrases = db2
                .Query<Phrase>("SELECT C.Id As CategoryId" +
                              " FROM Category AS C" +
                              " JOIN Phrase AS P ON C.Id =          P.CategoryId");
```

phrases has a type of `List<Phrase>`

Now I would like to find the first element of the list. But with my IDE when I hover over "phrases."  on another line all I see is the option to get a .count .add .addRange .find and similar.

Can someone explain how I can get the first element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `FirstOrDefault()`

```
var phrases = db2
                .Query<Phrase>(@"SELECT C.Id As CategoryId
                               FROM Category AS C
                               JOIN Phrase AS P ON C.Id = P.CategoryId").FirstOrDefault();
```